# Зависает основное приложение, что не так?

Tags: java, android, service

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    public static String ACTION_BROADCAST="com.eranewgames.bluetoothdoor.broadcast";
    BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        broadcastReceiver=new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                Log.e("MainActivity=onReceive", intent.getStringExtra("text"));
            }
        };

        IntentFilter intentFilter=new IntentFilter(MainActivity.ACTION_BROADCAST);
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver,intentFilter);

        startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this,ServiceBluetoothDoor.class));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        stopService(new Intent(MainActivity.this,ServiceBluetoothDoor.class));
        unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
    }
}
```

// Service

```
  public class ServiceBluetoothDoor extends Service {
    String macAddress = "70:72:0D:44:E6:1B";
    // SPP UUID сервиса
    private UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-6666-8000-00805F23534B");
    BluetoothSocket bluetoothSocket;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter=BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice=bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(macAddress);
        bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

        try{
            bluetoothSocket=bluetoothDevice.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
            bluetoothSocket.connect();

            BufferedReader bufferedReader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(bluetoothSocket.getInputStream()));
            String line;

            while ( (line=bufferedReader.readLine()) !=null ){
                Log.e("ServiceBluetoothDoor=onCreate", line);
//                Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.ACTION_BROADCAST);
//                intent.putExtra("text",dataInputStream.readUTF());
//                sendBroadcast(intent);
            }
            bufferedReader.close();

        } catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        try {
            bluetoothSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Зависает MainActivity, но почему ведь он с сервисом не связан

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Service` отрабатывает в UI потоке. Сделайте работу внутри сервиса в новом потоке, либо используйте `IntentService`

Comment: А разве Service не отдельный фоновый поток? что - то не понял вас.

Comment: @xTIGRx, нет, согласно документации сервис работает в основном, UI потоке

Comment: А IntentService может взаимодействовать с Activity через BroadCast чтобы Activity не зависало? Это надо чтобы из сервиса данные получить

Comment: @xTIGRx, с IntentService проблема в том, что он для единичных операций только годится - завершит задачу и помрёт. Лучше юзайте ваш сервис и просто вынесите всю работу в отдельный поток. ИМХО лучше сделать через RxJava

Comment: ааа. Теперь ясно. спасибо

Comment: Согласен с @ЮрийСПб что лучше работать через с помощью Rx.